# Bootstrap 4 carousel state transition issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, carousel

Bootstrap 4 carousel has an issue, while transitioning from one slide to another, it can show next slide before the previous one finishes its animation.

Somehow issue occurs extremely often when one of the items is selected in chrome inspector (but it happened on normal occasion as well). It can be reproduced even on default template (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/carousel/#)

html

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div class="row">

      <script src="/js/carousel.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/carousel.css">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
          <div class="carousel-inner w-100" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="" />
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next align-items-right" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="" />
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

js

```
  $('#recipeCarousel').carousel({
    interval: false
  });

  $('.carousel .carousel-item').each(function() {
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
      next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      next = next.next();
      if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
      }

      next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
  });
});
```

css

```
.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
  display: flex;
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-right.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-left.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {

  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-right.active,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
    transform: translateX(50%);
  }

  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-left.active,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {

  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-right.active,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
    transform: translateX(33.333333333%);
  }

  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-left.active,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
    transform: translateX(-33.333333333%);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {

  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-right.active,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
    transform: translateX(25%);
  }

  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-left.active,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
    transform: translateX(-25%);
  }
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-right,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-left {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.carousel-control-prev,
.carousel-control-next {
  width: 30px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5vghoyr3/

Comment: I do not see the described behaviour on either your fiddle nor on the linked website.
Which browser are you using and what exactly is the issue?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xB8stncIJZUH6Y4GU6pY376JMGd-ogmT here is said behavior, browser is chrome, os Windows, but occurs on linux as well